# ASP.NET MVC 3 Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller:

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private SomeDbEntities _db= new SomeDbEntities ();

    //
    // GET: /Item/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _db.Items.ToList();

        return View(items);
    }

    public ActionResult Decription(int id)
    {
        var item = _db.Items.Single(a => a.ItemID == id);

        return View(item); 
    }

}
```

and 2 views:

**Index.cshmtl**

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Item>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Description", new { id = item.ItemID})</li>
}
```

**Description.cshtml**

```
@model Web.Models.Item

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Decription";
 }

 <h2>Decription</h2>
 <p>@Model.Description</p>
```

**Route**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Item", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

And when i try to reach i.e. `http://localhost:12952/Item/Description/2` i am getting Server error:

`HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: Is your Cassini server running?

Comment: No. I am running it on usual ASP.NET Web Development Server.

Comment: @JakubKonecki wow! I didn't know it has a name. Cassini sounds good :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your action name is "Decription" while the url is "../Description/..". They don't match.

Comment: lol. tnx :) embarrassing